# Pipelight stopped functioning after HBO new web update in mid April, 2015

Tags: firefox, pipelight

I have got HBO Nordic working with Pipelight on Ubuntu 14.10 for long time. Suddenly a web portal update around the 12-13 of April made it stop working.

1. I can log into the HBO Nordic with my account. It works, for example, in an iPad app, so the account is OK.
2. The content is presented.
3. When I start the movie it wants to connect and if I, for example, show the same movie into the iPad, then I see the time position where it wants to continue.
4. The flash I suppose now only shows a progress circle without starting the movie.

Any ideas?

there is one solutiuon in webpage http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2274467

Comment: see solution in this webpage;

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few different solutions and the one that I found worked the best was to install Play On Linux first. Once you install that, install Firefox in Play on Linux. I tried it with IE, but the version was too old.

Comment: I run nowdays both hbo and netflix together with services like magine with pipelight. works fine.

play on linuxtakes more resources is my impression.